# Deploying PERN stack on AWS issue

Tags: javascript, express, amazon-ec2, deployment, react-fullstack

So I'm frustrated with this process I've watched the same tutorial a bunch on times https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/jeuwvi/deploying_full_stack_app_on_ubuntuaws_postgres/.

Everything seems perfect but the frontend doesn't seem to be making contact with the backend. Using xginx and pm2. In the config for the xginx my locations look like this

```
         location / {
                try_files $uri /index.html;
         }

         location /api {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
```

I'm not even sure if this is where the issue lies. I can hit my backend and database from insomnia to create a user and get a response back but when I do it from the actual site it sends the request to localhost3001 for some reason. I have environment variables set and all of that as well. It seems like each part are working separately fine but not together. Any suggestions? https://barn.bid/
Also this is the route from insomnia that made it so I could create a user 'https://barn.bid/api/users' (email,firstName,lastName,username,password) if you wish to see that working.
Any thoughts as to what could fix the problem or suggestions would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.env` makes the client side use the port 3001, which is same as the server side.

This leads to a conflict of port usage. Declare the port of client side.
Check this out: [Change Port Number](https://scriptverse.academy/tutorials/reactjs-change-port-number.html)